# Poor drop shadow on table with hidden empty cells

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+-------------------------+
|        SECTION 1        |
+-------+--------+--------+
|       | TYPE 1 | TYPE 2 |
+-------+--------+--------+
| KEY 1 | Val 1  | Val 2  |
+-------+--------+--------+
| KEY 2 | Val 3  | Val 4  |
+-------+--------+--------+
        |    SECTION 2    |
        +--------+--------+
        | TYPE 1 | TYPE 2 |
        +--------+--------+
        | Data 1 | Data 2 |
        +--------+--------+
        | Data 3 | Data 4 |
        +--------+--------+
        | Data 5 | Data 6 |
        +--------+--------+
```

Using `border-collapse: separate; empty-cells: hide;` on the table does exactly what I want, but when I apply a box-shadow with `box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #CCC`, the shadow surrounds the blank bottom left portion instead of tracing the irregular table edge I've shown above.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I can accomplish a proper drop-shadow on a table like this? Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aCuSk/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aCuSk/7/ Is this acceptable?

Comment: Ha! Thanks. I didn't realize it would be so easy. I should have tried that.